# What was the original Mac's (1984) development stack?

Tags: mac, development

What software did original Macintosh developers use and what were common languages used to write that software?

In short, I am wondering what the original development environment was like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was called [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop).

> Macintosh Programmer's Workshop or MPW, is a software development environment for the Classic Mac OS operating system, written by Apple Computer. For Macintosh developers, it was one of the primary tools for building applications for System 7.x and Mac OS 8.x and 9.x. Initially MPW was available for purchase, but Apple made it a free download after it was superseded by CodeWarrior. On Mac OS X it was replaced by the Project Builder IDE, which eventually became Xcode.

The languages used were Pascal (Object Oriented), C, and C++.

There is even a "fan" site ([Geek-Central](http://www.geek-central.gen.nz/MPW/intro.html)) that has additional info and download links.

Comment: Yeah, MPW came out several years in. First was Lisa programming, but then Lightspeed Pascal and C became available, among other similar tools, and much work was done there (or in assembler). There was also ResEdit, which is where all the graphic design happened.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the original Macintosh development environment was not on a Mac at all. Quoting from [this article](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=3rd_Party_Developers_and_Macintosh_Development.txt) on Folklore.org...

> Macintosh development in the early days (circa 1983-1985) was done
>   using the Apple Lisa computer and its Lisa Workshop development
>   environment

Most of the stories on folklore.org are written by the Apple employees who did the work and no longer work at Apple. A fascinating site. Careful, once you get started you may not come up for air for hours.